# How to change the default language of moderncv

Tags: moderncv

How can I change the default language of moderncv?

Comment: Everything is in this comment: what do you mean? (sorry to be sarcastic...)

Comment: I would just note that it isn't a good idea to go fiddling about in the TeX distribution; this directly compromises document portability.  It's better to just make the same customizations every time, or better yet write your own document class or package to distribute along with your documents.

Comment: I think you have to learn [how to ask a question](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). For an adequate problem description you need to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: @karlkoeller the use of the word 'default' was a red flag for me; changing 'defaults' compromises document portability

Answer (score 14):

Class `moderncv` has no build in predefined languages.  So you can't use a class option to switch the language to language "xyz".

But you can use package `babel` for pdfLaTeX to have proper writing rules working in your CV.  See the following short MWE for German language (lines 9--12):

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt
 ,a4paper
 ,sans
]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% german Language, new writing rules
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  %<========== Language German, new orthography

% Personal Data
\firstname{Max}
\familyname{Musterfrau}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Strasse Hausnummer}{PLZ Ort}{Deutschland}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{max@musterfrau.de}
\homepage{www.musterfrau.de}
\extrainfo{Zusatzinformationen}
\quote{Schlauer Spruch oder Zitat}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Ausbildung}
\cventry{Jahr--Jahr}{Fachbereich}{Universität}{Stadt}{\textit{Abschluss}}{Beschreibung}
\cventry{Jahr--Jahr}{Festkörperphysik}{Technische Hochschule}{München}{\textit{Diplom}}{Dies 
  ist ein extra besonders besonders langer Text, um einen ansonsten 
  unschönen Wortumbruch zu erzeugen. Dies ist ein langer Text, um einen 
  Wortumbruch zu erzeugen.}

\end{document}
```

Now you can write the complete CV in your language using the predefined macros from `moderncv`.

The result of the MWE is:

[image]

PS: I gave you this MWE just to show you how you can improve your next questions with your own MWE. Building a MWE can lead you to the solution, btw ...

Answer (score 2):

You simply don't have to. All sections and other content are inserted manually by the user, so just use for example "Educazione" (Italian) or "Educación" (Spanish)... instead of "Education" (English) in the section `\section{Education}` and so on.

Comment: *Educación in Español :)